# Swiftmailer Error Composer Install

Tags: installation, composer-php, swiftmailer

i am installing composer dependencies by 'composer install'.
it download bunch of packages but after swiftmailer it gives me error

```
[UnexpectedValueException]
'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\laravel-4\vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/72e34d......54c82f.1' is not a zip archive.
```

what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem happened due to the order composer was installing the files.
The work around that worked for me was to go into \vendor\composer\autoload_real.php and comment out the following line

```
require $vendorDir . '/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';
```

and then run composer again

Comment: there is no file named 'autoload_real.php' in \vendor\composer.There is only single file in \vendor\composer that is 'installed.json'.This file contains information about all installed packages.In this file there is no line that you above mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Running composer install with the --prefer-source option, fixed this problem for me.